# Continue build on failure

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

As said in the [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:continue_build_on_failure) we can continue build if one of the tasks has failed. But I can't get the point of that feature... Why do we need to execute other task if one of the tasks has been failed? Is it safe at all? Couldn't you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Yep it makes sense, for example generating classes from wsdl, in case of service not available.

Then you should provide some logic in your application for not working this service.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence in your linked doc says:

> This allows the build to complete sooner, **but hides other failures that would have occurred. In order to discover as many failures as possible in a single build execution, you can use the --continue option**.

So instead of failing on the first error just go and fail on all.  Imagine a webform that only tells you each error at a time after submitting and it takes you ages to fill it out versus a form that shows you all you current of your current errors at once.

Examples are obviously include developing the original gradle file and testing it with your build.  Or running on an integration service, where you would rather have "all" the errors at once instead of hitting the build button all the day.

> If a task fails, any subsequent tasks that were depending on it will not be executed, as it is not safe to do so.

So you will most likely not end up with the result you are expecting.  But could!  That is on you to decide, as it depends on your build and what you are doing.  So, 'it safe?  Heck no.  But sometimes we all have to do unsafe things...

If you want to get rid of something failing, that is not vital to the actual build result (e.g. the jar file you are after) but is part of the build process (e.g. a codenarc task as part of the tests) and you would rather fix a critical bug with ugly code, you might be better off to just exclude that task (`gradle jar -x codenarc`) instead of using this feature.  Is this safe?  Heck no... you get the picture!